# NLog doesn't work in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm trying to use NLog with an Azure Web App. Everything works on my local PC, but when I deploy to Azure it doesn't work at all.
I've tried with different targets like file and Azure table storage. Both work perfectly on my PC but not in Azure.
I'm using asp.net core.

Here is my NLog config for the table storage.
**Note:** this configuration works when I execute the program from my local PC. I can see the entries in the Azure table storage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
  >

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>

    <target xsi:type="AzureTableStorage" name="allfile" 
            PartitionKey="nlog-all-${date}.${logger}"
            RowKey="${ticks}.${guid}"
            ConnectionString="**REMOVED**"
            tableName="**REMOVED**"
                 layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />

    <target xsi:type="AzureTableStorage" name="ownFile"
            PartitionKey="nlog-own-${date}.${logger}"
            RowKey="${ticks}.${guid}"
            ConnectionString="**REMOVED**"
            tableName="**REMOVED**"
              layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>

    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a whole lot more information than that.  Let's start off with either your NLog configuration file, or the code that is setting up your logging.  Something off the top of my head is what folder are you trying to log to.

Comment: Are you able to go SCM/Kudos side (https://your-website-blah-blah.scm.azurewebsites.net) & check the nlog.config?

Comment: Also from event log can you application (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/07/01/how-to-view-the-event-logs-of-your-azure-app-service/) & see if there are any other errors?

Comment: Thanks @Umang ! I noticed that the config file was not up to date. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the configuration file *NLog.config* was not getting updated (or is being overwritten) in Azure.
Renaming the configuration file to something different solved my problem.
However, I consider this a **workaround** only.

The *NLog.config* in Azure seems to be the one coming as example, and contains no targets at all.

Comment: You could click `Remove additional files at destination` when you publish your project. And then it will always get the latest configuration you have set.

Comment: How are you deploying, and is the NLog configuration file flagged with a **Build Action** of `Content`, and **Copy to Output Dir** is `true`?

Comment: This is caused by using the nuget-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config . Microsoft simplified the nuget-package-framework, so a lot of package broke (including this). The advice is not to use this package in your application. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLog-Install